# lighttpd: why using port >= 9000 does not work properly

Tags: web-server, port, lamp, lighttpd

I had a lighttpd server which works normally. I can access this website from outside(non-localhost) via http://vm.aaa.com:8080. Let's just assume that it's a simple static website, without php or mysql.

Now I want to copy this website as a test one(using another port) in the same machine. And I do not want to use virtual host. So I just copy the whole files of original server, including lighttpd's bin/ conf/ htdocs/ lib/ and so on folders. And I made some required change, including changing lighttpd.conf.

Now what I'm confused is, if change the port to a number that is less than 9000, it works perfectly. But if the port is changed to a number that is equal or greater than 9000, lighttpd can start, but I can not access the new website from outside, while I do can access the new website from INSIDE(I mean in the same LAN or localhost).

The access log from INSIDE is like below:

```
vm.aaa.com:9876 10.46.175.117 - - [08/Oct/2012:13:18:47 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" " curl/7.12.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.12.1 OpenSSL/0.9.7a zlib/1.2.1.2 libidn/0.5.6"
```

Command I used to start lighttpd is:

```
bin/lighttpd -f conf/lighttpd.conf -m lib/ -D
```

My lighttpd.conf is like:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_accesslog",
)
var.rundir = "/home/work/lighttpd_9876"
server.port = 9876
server.bind = "0.0.0.0"
server.pid-file = var.rundir + "/log/lighttpd.pid"
server.document-root        = var.rundir + "/htdocs/"
var.cronolog_path = "/home/work/lighttpd_9876/cronolog/sbin/cronolog"
server.errorlog = ...
accesslog.filename = ...
...
```

So why is this happening? I've tried several diffrent ports, still the same. Isn't that ports between 8000 and 65535 are the same?

Comment: Ports above 32767 are generally considered to be for use with outbound sockets, and should be avoided for listeners. Anyway, what does netstat -apn say if you do configure a port above 9000 and start lighttpd?

Comment: @rackandboneman He said that he can access the service from localhost and other hosts on the LAN, so the issue most likely isn't with lighttpd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ports above 9000 are being blocked somewhere between your server and the external client. Check with `nmap -sT -Pn -p 9876 vm.aaa.com` and contact your firewall admin (or your ISP) about the issue.